# Three.js transform controls not interactive (won't click or hover)

Tags: three.js

I'm playing about with three.js and webGL with an attempt to get html objects overlaid on a webGL model.

I intend to use three.js object loaders to render a 3D model, where I can then allow users to overlay HTML DOM objects in 3D space via a custom UI.

I've mainly been using the various different examples in the three.js docs (https://threejs.org/examples/ and https://codepen.io/AdamEDGE/pen/RRjEwz).

In order to allow the user to move the overlaid HTML objects via the UI, I've added the transform controls (https://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_transform.html).
Things seemed to be going relatively well up to this point, but now I see that the controls are not hoverable or clickable to move the element.
I suspect I'm either missing code or an issue with the camera not aligning correctly, but I'm very new to this so I'm guessing.

I have also experimented with Jerome Etienne's blending tutorials, but on testing that caused other issues and I think may not be worth the trouble for what I'm going for (http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2013/04/30/closing-the-gap-between-html-and-webgl/index.html).

I have created an example that shows the problem (click on an object and the controls should show).
Its a simple webGL torus with two HTML images overlaid and mapped to a Mesh so I can link the controls to the HTML elements which are on a different scene.

https://jsfiddle.net/mattscotty/h5wuq86y/

```
control = new THREE.TransformControls(camera, glRenderer.domElement);
control.addEventListener('change', render);
```

The controls show on all the correct places when clicked as expected and I can use the keyboard to change the transform type (again see https://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_transform.html for how it should work).
As I can't click or hover, I can't hook up to the relevant events.

I'm brand new to this and I'm quite sure I'm missing something obvious, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your fiddle does not work. Check the console for errors.

Comment: Hi, try now, i suspect it was a http(s) mixed content issue.